# changing colour of results from terminal commands

Tags: terminal, colors

When I call commands in a terminal the results are shown in grey.  How can I change the colour to white?  With dircolors on some other easy way.

Comment: What terminal do you use? On what operating system?

Comment: Trisquel Gnu using Terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `gnome-terminal`, you can open the preferences (Edit=>Preferences) and find the default setting on the left side, click it and go to the colors tab where you can edit the configurations:

[image: screenshot of gnome-terminal color preferences] .

Comment: Thank you, have used profile preferences in terminator and changed to Built-in scheme to be `White on Black`.